# How to use filter result from response file in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core

```
var travelTekList = TravelTek.ParseXml(response, typeof(Model.Cruise.response));   
var cruiseList = ((ImmersionHospitality.core.Model.Cruise.response)travelTekList).results.ToList();
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you share your response and what data you want to filter from it?